# Rails Engines: How to write tests that depend upon main app models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

The [Rails Engines](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) documentation was really quite good for understanding how to write engines. However, it left me with a question which I've been unable to answer.

Say I'm writing the engine discussed in the documentation (a blog). The `Post` model doesn't need to know anything about its author, and this engine doesn't need to deal with accounts in any way, but it makes sense for posts to *have* an author, so we make the class for the author configurable and we say that the `Post` model `belongs_to` it. The engine will simply make use of whatever account scheme is in use in the main application.

How then do we write tests for the `Post` model if the engine doesn't contain a model for the author? I'm using FactoryGirl and I tried just putting together a factory for a user, but it doesn't work without a corresponding table. I suppose I could create a basic `Author` class within the generated `test/dummy` application, but then all the tests would have to be put in there as well, which feels a little nasty to me (I just want my tests in an obvious place, I guess).

Comment: I am in the same situation help!!!

Comment: Sorry to see that this never got answered. I'm looking for an answer to this as well.

Comment: Sorry guys! I actually forgot that I asked this question. I did end up figuring this out-- please see the answer I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is actually quite simple: use the `test/dummy` application. Generate the Author class within `test/dummy`, but write a factory for it in `test/factories` and use it like anything else. You don't have to write any tests within the dummy application. More information (including a quick tutorial) is [here](https://kyrofa.com/posts/rails-writing-engine-tests-that-depend-on-main-application-models/).